# Prove that $\vec{EA}+\vec{EB}+\vec{EC}+\vec{ED}=2\vec{EO}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vector-spaces

Let there be a circle $(O,R)$ and $AB,CD$ two perpendicular chords of that circle that intersect on point $E$. Prove that $\vec{EA}+\vec{EB}+\vec{EC}+\vec{ED}=2\vec{EO}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ \vec{ OA} + \vec{ OB} + \vec{ OC} + \vec{ OD}= 2 \vec{ OM} $ in circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565908/vec-oa-vec-ob-vec-oc-vec-od-2-vec-om-in-circle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prove it parallel to $\vec{AB}$, then prove it parallel to $\vec{CD}$.

To prove it parallel to $\vec{AB}$, say, let $X$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $O$ to $\vec{AB}$, then express $\vec{EA}$ in terms of $\vec{AX}$ and $\vec{EX}$, and $\vec{EB}$ in terms of $\vec{BX}$ and $\vec{EX}$; then use the fact that $\vec{AX} = \vec{BX}$.

You can fill in the details from here.

Comment: Prove what parallel to AB and CD?? AB and CD intercept on point E, how can they be parallel???

Comment: Nevermind, I just solved it. All I needed was two saggitas OX and OY. Thanks for giving me the idea

Comment: @nick: We have a vector equation in the form $\vec{x} = \vec{y}$. By "prove parallel to $\vec{AB}$", I meant: prove that the component of $\vec{x}$ in direction $\vec{AB}$ is equal to the component of $\vec{y}$ in direction $\vec{AB}$.