# $ \vec{ OA} + \vec{ OB} + \vec{ OC} + \vec{ OD}= 2 \vec{ OM} $ in circle

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, analytic-geometry, circles

Consider two perpendicular chords $AB$ and $CD$ of a given
circle and ${M} = AB ∩ CD$. Show that $
\vec{
OA} +
\vec{
OB} +
\vec{
OC} +
\vec{
OD}= 2
\vec{
OM} .$

I tried to write the vectors as :
$$\vec{OA}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MA}, \vec{OB}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MB}, \vec{OC}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MC}, \vec{OD}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MD} $$ but it won't reduce when adding them. Can somebody give me another tips, please?

Comment: Is $O$ meant to be the center of the circle? Regardless, please explicitly state what it is, including if it is just any arbitrary point, in the question.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66104

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ and $Q$ be mid-points of $CD$ and $AB$.

Thus, $$(\vec{
OA} +
\vec{
OB}) +
(\vec{
OC} +
\vec{
OD})=2\vec{OQ}+2\vec{OP}= 2
\vec{
OM} $$